# Ninject "custom" DBContext binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am currently working on a dummy MVC project (to try out some new things), but I am having issue with Injecting my DatabaseContext into my service...

You can find my code below:

My DatabaseContext:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MacAddress> MacAddresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

My service & interface into which I'd like to inject my context:

```
public interface IMacAddressService
{
    List<MacAddress> GetAllMacAddresses();
}

public class MacAddressService : IMacAddressService
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public MacAddressService(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public List<MacAddress> GetAllMacAddresses()
    {
        return _context.MacAddresses.ToList();
    }
}
```

What binding can I apply on my IKernel to inject my DatabaseContext properly?

For your information:

- I am already able to bind classes so there's nothing wrong with my Ninject setup, I just need to know how to bind this specific context
- I googled but all I could find was how to bind the DbContext to itself...
- I use a custom DbContext as seen in an EF tutorial so that I can use my DbSets in my services (I will later use repositories for this)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use any abstraction to pass the `DatabaseContext` to your service, so Ninject will resolve it without any extra configuration.

If you want to configure the binding explicitly you can use `Bind<DatabaseContext>().ToSelf()`

**EDIT**

I just noticed that your `DatabaseContext` constructor is protected

```
protected DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext")
{
}
```

You need to make it public to be able to create instances of `DatabaseContext`

Comment: Thanks, this solved it after I made the constructor of `DatabaseContext`  public :)